# I want to start a new animation every time I click with requestFrameAnimation

Tags: javascript, html, requestanimationframe

I'm having multiple issues.

1. <strike>Everytime I click the animation goes faster.</strike> SOLVED @Jorge Fuentes González
2. <strike>Everytime I click the
   last animation stops moving</strike> SOLVED @Kaiido

I have changed about everything I could think of around and still the same issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
    function drawFrame(frameX, frameY, canvasX, canvasY) {
      ctx.drawImage(img,
                    frameX * width, frameY * height,
                    width, height,
                    x_click, y_click,
                    scaledWidth, scaledHeight);
    }

    // Number of frames in animation
    var cycleLoop = [3, 2, 1, 0, 7, 6, 5];
    // Position of sprite in sheet
    var currentLoopIndex = 0;
    var frameCount = 0;

    function step() {

      frameCount++;
      if (frameCount < 30) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
        return;
      }
      frameCount = 0;
      // ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      drawFrame(cycleLoop[currentLoopIndex++], 0, 0, 0);
      // Starts animation over
      if (currentLoopIndex >= cycleLoop.length) {
        // If you want to loop back in oposite direction after full animation
        cycleLoop.reverse();
        // Reseting position of which sprite to use
        currentLoopIndex = 0;
      }
      window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    }

    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", getPosition, false);
    function getPosition(event) {
       x_click = event.x;
       y_click = event.y;

       x_click -= canvas.offsetLeft * 10;
       y_click -= canvas.offsetTop * 10;
       step();
    }
```

==============================
JS Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/HYUTS/q4fazt6L/9/

=======================================

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this? will be easy for others to help

Comment: I learned how to use imgur for img.src =""  :)

Comment: You have issues, ok, but what were you expecting to see?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to add a **new** animated object at every click?

Comment: @Kaiido Correct.

Comment: @HYUTS You would have to save every variable inside an object and make step() part of the object too. Then you could have multiple animated objects, calling this.step() inside their step functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step in your situation, is to create different objects for every *animatables*, so they can be drawn and updated independently.

After, you will have to split your logic in several parts.

A basic setup is to have one main loop that runs constantly in the background, and which will call all higher level objects update function, then all the drawing functions.

It's in these higher level methods that you will do the checks as to whether they should actually be discarded or not. The main loop doesn't have to take care of it.

In the example below, I created a class for your *animatable* objects. These objects will now have their own status, and will be able to update as they wish independently of others.

With this setup, adding a new Object in the scene is just a matter of pushing it in an Array.

```js
// Our Animatable class (ES5 style...)
// Each object as its own frameCount and its own loopIndex
function Animatable(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.frameCount = 0;
  this.loopIndex = 0;
  this.cycleLoop = [3, 2, 1, 0, 7, 6, 5];
}
Animatable.prototype = {
  update: function() {
    this.frameCount++;
    if (this.frameCount < 30) {
      return;
    }
    this.frameCount = 0;
    this.loopIndex++
      if (this.loopIndex >= this.cycleLoop.length) {
        // If you want to loop back in oposite direction after full animation
        this.cycleLoop.reverse();
        // Reseting position of which sprite to use
        this.loopIndex = 0;
      }
  },
  draw: function() {
    // check the image is loaded
    if (!img.naturalWidth) return;
    var frameX = this.cycleLoop[this.loopIndex];
    ctx.drawImage(img,
      frameX * width, 0,
      width, height,
      this.x - scaledWidth/2, this.y - scaledHeight/2,
      scaledWidth, scaledHeight);
  }
};

// the main anim loop, independent
function startAnimLoop() {

  animloop();
  
  function animloop() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animloop);
    // updates
    animatables.forEach(update);
    // drawings
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    animatables.forEach(draw);
  }

  function update(animatable) {
    animatable.update();
  }

  function draw(animatable) {
    animatable.draw();
  }
}



// one image for all
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://imgur.com/u2hjhwq.png';
img.onload = startAnimLoop;

// here we will hold all our objects
var animatables = [new Animatable(50, 50)]; // start with a single one

var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// some constant from OP's fiddle
var scale = 1.5;
var width = 100; // Bigger numbers push left <-, smaller right ->
var height = 100;
var scaledWidth = scale * width;
var scaledHeight = scale * height;


canvas.onclick = function(evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  var x = evt.clientX - rect.left;
  var y = evt.clientY - rect.top;
  // we simply create a new object ;-)
  animatables.push(new Animatable(x, y));
};
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Perfect! @Kaiido Thank you so much! Works just how I wanted. I'm going to study it now.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you click, you call `step();`, which will call `window.requestAnimationFrame(step);`, which will call `step()` the next animation frame. I don't see any stop point so the loop will be called forever.

So, when you call `step()` the first time, `step()` will be called continuously for ever, and if you click again, another `step()` "line" will be called a second time which will call `window.requestAnimationFrame(step);` for ever again, so now you will have two "lines" calling `step()`. That's why the animation goes faster, because on each animation frame `step()` will be called twice, doubling the calculations.

What you have to do is to check if the animation is already running (with a flag) and do not run it again, or to `window.cancelAnimationFrame(ID)` before starting the `step()` loop again. Note that on each click you must restart the variables that control the animation, like `frameCount` and `currentLoopIndex`

```
function drawFrame(frameX, frameY, canvasX, canvasY) {
  ctx.drawImage(img,
                frameX * width, frameY * height,
                width, height,
                x_click, y_click,
                scaledWidth, scaledHeight);
}

// Number of frames in animation
var cycleLoop = [3, 2, 1, 0, 7, 6, 5];
// Position of sprite in sheet
var currentLoopIndex = 0;
var frameCount = 0;

var animationid = null;
function step() {

  frameCount++;
  if (frameCount < 30) {
    animationid = window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    return;
  }
  frameCount = 0;
  // ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawFrame(cycleLoop[currentLoopIndex++], 0, 0, 0);
  // Starts animation over
  if (currentLoopIndex >= cycleLoop.length) {
    // If you want to loop back in oposite direction after full animation
    cycleLoop.reverse();
    // Reseting position of which sprite to use
    currentLoopIndex = 0;
  }
  animationid = window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", getPosition, false);
function getPosition(event) {
   x_click = event.x;
   y_click = event.y;

   x_click -= canvas.offsetLeft * 10;
   y_click -= canvas.offsetTop * 10;
   frameCount = currentLoopIndex = 0;
   window.cancelAnimationFrame(animationid);
   step();
}
```

Comment: It makes sense now that you explained it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

window.requestAnimationFrame is still running when you click again, and when you click you add another tick per frame to your animation, doubling your speed, as step() is called two times each frame now. You should cancel the previous animation frame when clicking again, using window.cancelAnimationFrame()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/cancelAnimationFrame

Like this:

```
...
var animationID;

//in step() save the id in every call
function step() {
    ...
    animationID = window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    ...
}

//In getPosition cancel the current animation
function.getPosition(event) {
    ...
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(animationId);
    ...
}
```

And if you want multiple animations running, create an object for each and make the function step() their property, then run `window.requestAnimationFrame(this.step)` inside of step(). You'd also have to save every variable needed for the animation like `currentLoopIndex` as part of the object.